# Member function pointer calls copy constructor?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, lookup-tables

I'm trying to create a lookup table of member functions in my code, but it seems to be trying to call my copy constructor, which I've blocked by extending an "uncopyable" class. What I have is something like the following.

```
enum {FUN1_IDX, FUN2_IDX, ..., NUM_FUNS };

class Foo {
  fun1(Bar b){ ... }
  fun2(Bar b){ ... }
  ...
  void (Foo::*lookup_table[NUM_FUNS])(Bar b);
  Foo(){ 
    lookup_table[FUN1_IDX] = &Foo::fun1;
    lookup_table[FUN2_IDX] = &Foo::fun2;
  }

  void doLookup(int fun_num, Bar b) {
    (this->*lookup_table[fun_num])(b);
  }
};
```

The error is that the '(this->...' line tries to call the copy constructor, which is not visible. Why is it trying to do this, and what do I have to change so it won't?

Comment: Could you post the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: Are you talking about the Foo copy constructor or the Bar copy constructor? If the Bar, then this is a really basic issue (answered below by litb). If the Foo, then please post a compileable code sample, because when I filled in the ...s and made Foo inherit from an uncopyable class, this worked just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make them reference parameters.

```
enum {FUN1_IDX, FUN2_IDX, ..., NUM_FUNS };

class Foo {
  fun1(Bar &b){ ... }
  fun2(Bar &b){ ... }
  ...
  void (Foo::*lookup_table[NUM_FUNS])(Bar &b);
  Foo(){ 
    lookup_table[FUN1_IDX] = &Foo::fun1;
    lookup_table[FUN2_IDX] = &Foo::fun2;
  }

  void doLookup(int fun_num, Bar &b) {
    (this->*lookup_table[fun_num])(b);
  }
};
```

In C++, otherwise such plain parameters don't just reference objects, but they are those objects themselves. Making them reference parameters will merely reference what is passed. In this matter, C++ has the same semantics as C (in which you would use pointers for that).

Comment: Thank you. I was confused by the error message because both Foo and Bar were uncopyable, and I thought it was trying to copy Foo. Of course it was trying to copy Bar.